# c3p0 default connection tester - how are errors handled?

Tags: java, jdbc, c3p0

If a connection is invalid an exception is thrown however I've been unable to determine where this exception is handled from `DefaultConnectionTester.java`.  What happens to this exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

c3p0 ConnectionTesters should handle any Exception during a test by returning ConnectionTester.CONNECTION_IS_INVALID. That's what c3p0's DefaultConnectionTester does. It doesn't throw an Exception, it catches it and handles it by reporting that the Connection is bad and should be expired from the pool.

(For Exceptions whose occurrence implies that all pooled Connections are likely bad, DATABASE_IS_INVALID is reported.)

If you'd like the see the Exceptions that occur during tests, set the log level of com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester to FINE (or DEBUG in log4j).